# What is the path to your apps "assets" folder in Android?

Tags: android, video, path

I am developing an Android App and would like to have a video file (mp4) bundled inside the .apk so that when the app is launched I can play a short intro video.

Unfortunately I'm having trouble figuring out where in my project folder I should place this video file, and also how to access it (the path to the file).

I am using `videoView.setVideoPath();`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Its a shame, that their "demo" for the video element does not covers such basic things, but leave a blank `path = "";` there. (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put it in res\raw folder.  Then in code use this uri: "android.resource://com.mypackagename/raw/myvideosample"

Comment: It worked!  Thanks.  As an additional note for future readers, you should omit the file extension.  Mine would only work when I omitted the file extension from the path.

Comment: Thanks dude. I searched this code many places, Thanks for this valuable code.

Comment: @Orsol i used yor answer but getting this error  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
sqlite3_open_v2("android.resource://com.android.mds.calculator/raw/calculator", &handle, 2, NULL) failed

Comment: @vnshetty, how you use Sqlite, this answer has nothing relevant to it

Comment: @Orsol  i have one sqlite file and placed it in raw folder and i try to open that file by giving myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("android.resource://com.android.mds.calculator/raw/calculator", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY); but getting above error

Comment: @Orsol: I believe that issue is in database file not the path. Try this guide http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ to use your own database.

Answer (score 1):

You should put it in /res/raw and access it with

```
getResources().openRawResource(id)
```

Find more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromCode).

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this, but I believe that setVideoPath() is looking for the path to a file (String), not a resource ID.  It wouldn't play when I used this technique.