# Play a resource video using Android's MediaPlayer class

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I save a video, `test.mp4`, in my project's `res/raw` directory. I have my `SurfaceView` declared as such:

```
  <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
  </SurfaceView>
```

Then, in my activity's `onCreate ()` method, I have the following:

```
private MediaPlayer mp;
private SurfaceView view;
private SurfaceHolder holder;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    view = (SurfaceView) findViewById (R.id.surface);
    holder = view.getHolder();
    holder.setKeepScreenOn (true); 
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this.getBaseContext (), R.raw.test);
    mp.setDisplay (holder);
    mp.setLooping (true);
    mp.start();
}
```

I don't get why it doesn't show the video, even if I set the display. I'm running on API 7 (2.1.1) and I get the audio. I need a Video-only type of interface, without the control panel. As far as I know, `VideoView`, although simpler than `MediaPlayer`, has a built-in control layer. Also, I don't see a way to use `VideoView` on a resource. If there are workarounds for these two issues I have, or if my assumption of `VideoView` is wrong, I'd appreciate being told.

---

**UPDATE:** I am currently using the `VideoView` class. My assumption really was wrong about automatically having a UI control panel. Still, I have NOT been able to play videos stored in `res/raw` via the `MediaPlayer` class; it always fails when I call `prepare ()` or the audio plays, but the video doesn't. Because of this, my question still stands.

If anyone runs into my question about how I used VideoView, let me save you some trouble in looking for how to retrieve a video in `res/raw`. The following snippet assumes you have a `VideoView` with an id of `view` in a layout file, `main.xml`:

```
public class generalActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate (icicle);
        this.setContent (R.layout.main);

        // You know the that view is an instance of VideoView, so cast it as such
        VideoView v = (VideoView) this.findViewById (R.id.view);

        // This is the name of the video WITHOUT the file extension.
        // In this example, the name of the video is 'test.mp4'
        String videoName = "test"

        // You build the URI to your video here
        StringBuilder uriPathBuilder = new StringBuilder ();
        uriPathBuilder.append ("android.resource://");
        uriPathBuilder.append (this.getPackageName ());
        uriPathBuilder.append (File.separator);
        uriPathBuilder.append ("raw");
        uriPathBuilder.append (File.separator);
        uriPathBuilder.append (videoName);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse (uriPathBuilder.toString ());

        view.setVideoURI (uri);
        view.start ();
    }
}
```

Here's the link that I used as a reference to get the uri path: [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448393/what-is-the-path-to-your-apps-assets-folder-in-android/3448604#3448604)

I'm leaving this open because I asked if I could play video in `res/raw` using MediaPlayer, and not `VideoView`. Even if I got it to work the way I wanted using `VideoView`, as far as I know, there are still things `MediaPlayer` can do that `VideoView` can't. I could be wrong though, so if you just need to show a video and don't need anything advanced, I'm pretty sure `VideoView` will suffice.

Oh, and thanks to @Ravi for all the help.

Comment: I think VideoView is missing here.

Comment: as far as I know, `VideoView` is a wrapper for `MediaPlayer`. I chose to use `MediaPlayer` over `VideoView`.

Comment: Playing from VideoView is easier I think.

Comment: but doesn't `VideoView` have a control panel? I need to play videos without the control panel.

Comment: You can play video without control panel in VideoView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to use [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) instead of MediaPlayer, as it wraps the player, the surface and the holder for you, if you fail to see the video in VideoView, then maybe the video file cannot be played on android.

Comment: is there a way to block off videoview's controls, cause I need the controls hidden

Comment: @BinyaminSharet yeah but Views leak Context.  If you need your playback to persist in a user-pleasant manner then, unfortunately, VideoView is not an option.  You must retain the MediaPlayer and destroy and recreate the Surface[View].

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `setDisplay` API when the surface is created.

Implement the `SurfaceHolder.Callback` and set the type of surface to push buffers `setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS)`

Also where are you calling the `setDataSource` API?

You can always take a look at the [VideoView.java](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java) to see how the media player is implemented :)

Comment: I'm not calling `setDataSource ()`. I was under the impression that `MediaPlayer.create ()` took care of that for me. Also, the API states the `SurfaceHolder.setType ()` is deprecated.

Comment: I see now that it is indeed deprecated, was not when I referred to it my apologies. But you need to pass the resource id to `MediaPlayer.create()` but you seem to be passing the surface holder obj..

Comment: sorry, I yanked the wrong code. I was trying out the 3 argument version of `MediaPlayer.create ()`. Where you could specify the `SurfaceHolder`.

Comment: Okay, the surface is not created in the `onCreate` method, you need to tell android to notify you when the surface is created. So register for the callback from the `SurfaceHolder` and in the `SurfaceCreated` callback use the surfaceholder obj to set the display and then start the mediaplayer.

Comment: still doesn't work. I had my class implement `SurfaceHolder.Callback` and had the `surfaceCreated` call `mp`'s `addDisplay ()` and `start ()` methods, but I still get a blank screen.

Comment: are you calling `prepare()` before calling `start()` and after calling `setDisplay`? Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) state diagram for the media player. Are you getting any error's in the logcat? can you play the file using the gallery app on android?

Comment: @anonymous let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2799/discussion-between-ravi-and-anonymous)